# Disable checkbox ColumnMenu kogrid

Tags: jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, kogrid

I have a ko-grid like that http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples. And I want to disable a specific checkbox in Column Menu as below image. How can I do it?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMnYM.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: put your code, please

Comment: Hi, was the answer helpful? If not could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

That website needs to update it's Plunkers, it's calling insecure http resources, and none of the examples are displaying.

Anyway, to disable a specific checkbox, disable the details of that corresponding row. Like this:

```
this.myData = ko.observableArray([{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                                  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, disable: true}, //the row you want disabled
                                  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                                  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                                  {name: "Enos", age: 34}]);
```

Let me know if it works.